# paypal payment integration in azure webrole

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, azure, paypal

I am new to Windows Azure and I need paypal payment integration in my web role.

How can I implement paypal without using an asp.net session variable? Is there any solution to achieve it or is it mandatory to have session variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to use session variable in Windows Azure instead you can use Windows Azure Cache for this purpose and it is done in past as well. Try to use Azure Cache, where it is needed and more info about Azure cache, you can get at link below:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278356